# Sticky sidebar with scrollable content on x-axis

Tags: html, css

When having a sticky sidebar and scrollable content on the x axis, position sticky stops being sticky at a certain point. It seems like it has something to do with overflow and sticky cant deal with that.
So how do make the sidebar stick at all times to the side?

I made a example on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qt3eL1o4/2/

```css
.align {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.ul {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <ul class="ul">
    <li class="time">
      <p>21:00</p>
    </li>
    <li class="time">
      <p>22:00</p>
    </li>
    <li class="time">
      <p>23:00</p>
    </li>
    <li class="time">
      <p>00:00</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sticky still works, but the whole HTML page starts scrolling left. You can clearly see it when you place the whole scrolling div outside of the `align` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `left:0`  to `.ul` and  `overflow-x:scroll`  to `.align`

```css
.align {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x:scroll
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.ul {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: yellow;
  left:0
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <ul class="ul">
    <li class="time">
      <p>21:00</p>
    </li>
    <li class="time">
      <p>22:00</p>
    </li>
    <li class="time">
      <p>23:00</p>
    </li>
    <li class="time">
      <p>00:00</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
      <p>
        - Det her er blevet en form for manddomsprøve. Det er jo en flertalsregering, og hvis den begynder at bakke på et af de allerførste forslag, fordi det er upopulært, og fordi regeringen kommer i modvind, så siger det også noget om regeringen, siger Jesper
        Vestergren.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```